Count data with time-varying covariates
One way to model count data is to simply count up the number of events as the outcome with an offset of observation time if this varies between people. I presume it's also possible to model count data if you have an important exposure variable that you might like to include in a time-dependent manner - i.e. the data is then formatted into counting process form. So here you would have differing observation times split at the time of exposure change, counting up the number of events in each interval, and still specifying the interval length as an exposure?
Do you need to do anything to adjust the standard errors in this case? i.e. does the model assume independence between rows, or is it like the Cox model, where this doesn't matter. Does a standard glm work or do I need to look at something that accounts for the potential correlation like a gl(mixed)m?
